# text>:6:0: unexpected end of input in knitr packaage

Tags: r, knitr

I'm facing the following error, when executing the following lines in r markdown using the knitr package:

```
library(knitr)
data <- read.delim('src/1.QC_mito/percent_mito.txt',sep='\t',header=T)
kable(data, "html") %>%
kable_styling() %>%
#scroll_box(width = "810px",height = "200px")
```

Error:

```
2021-08-27T17:58:39.802+02:00   <text>:6:0: unexpected end of input

2021-08-27T17:58:39.802+02:004: kable_styling() %>%
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is incomplete.  The 4th line ends with `%>%`, and the last line is commented out, so R complains that the expression is incomplete.  Just delete the comment marker or the pipe symbol at the end of the 4th line.